# How to get JWK URL for epic fhir resources?

Tags: python, hl7-fhir, jwk, smart-on-fhir

Im using open epic documentation (https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2)
I'm able to create application
But in bottom it asked me upload public key and also add jwk url (which is not required) but for accessing the public key I feel i need to add this to for authenticating user.[here is the image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXx2g.png)

I don't know from where will i get this JWK URL.
In many documentation it was mentioned to hit

```
GET https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/R4/.well-known/smart-configuration HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
```

the above endpoint to get jwk url . But there is nothing related to it.
or
do i need to create an endpoint in my project and then pass it here. if yes, then what should that API looks like.
I'm using djangorestframework. If anyone can help me with this that would be grate.

Answer (score 1):

That is a URL that you set up and host. This URL points to your JWKS that contains the public key(s) for your app. When you go through the authentication flow, you will sign the JWT with your private key. The Epic instance you are connecting to will lookup the correct public key from that specified URL and use the public key to validate the authenticity of the JWT. There's some info [here](https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2&section=JWKS) that describes hosting the URL and the format of the key set.

Comment: I got you there . but how do I need to create a JWK URL and how to set the public key into there .

Comment: Creating and hosting it will be much like creating and hosting webpages for a website. You'll need a domain or web server of some kind that is publicly reachable, and that URL should point to the JWKS. The easiest thing to do is to create a JSON file with the public key(s) and host that somewhere within your domain, then provide the URL to the JSON file.